# Проблема с миграциями БД для Flask

Tags: python, flask

У меня есть файл app.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_script import Manager
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
from config import Config

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
app.config.from_object(Config)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
from models import Users

migrate = Migrate(app, db)
manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

есть файл models.py

```
from app import db, app
from datetime import date, datetime


# As example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y8i_UjuqunQ
class Users(db.Model):
    # Users
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(128))
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(128))
    created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now())
    user_days = db.relationship("Days", back_populates="user_days")
    user_tasks = db.relationship("Tasks", back_populates="user_tasks")
    user_chats = db.relationship("Chats", back_populates="user_chats")

    def __init__(self, username, last_name, first_name):
        self.username = username
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.first_name = first_name

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User {}>'.format(self.username)
```

Далее когда я применяю миграцию (или создание БД) через

```
python app.py db init
python app.py db migrate
python app.py db upgrade
```

То получаю ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 12, in <module>
    from models import Users
  File "C:\Users\vandr\PycharmProjects\telegrambot_with_flask\models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import db, app
  File "C:\Users\vandr\PycharmProjects\telegrambot_with_flask\app.py", line 12, in <module>
    from models import Users
ImportError: cannot import name 'Users'
```

Не создается БД, не создается миграция

Answer (score 1):

В терминале, в вашем виртуальном окружении где установлен Flask, выполнить:

```
(venv)$ flask db init
(venv)$ flask db migrate -m "Тут текст коммита"
(venv)$ flask db upgrade
```

Если вы используете PyCharm, то терминал в нём сразу работает в контексте вашего виртуального окружения. venv в данном примере - это имя виртуального окружения. После выполнения команды flask db migrate рекомендуется проверить корректность получившегося файла миграции, который находится в папке versions. После этого можно делать upgrade.

Comment: Не получается так сделать. Точнее команды-то я делаю, но так как flask db не видит мои модели, то он создает пустую базу или дропает при апгрейде уже созданную базу. Не могу понять как правильно (из отдельного файла) передать модели, чтобы flask db создал правильную миграцию.

Comment: Попробуйте так импортировать: **from app.models import Users** и перенести эту строку выше, где делаются все импорты

Comment: еще в app.py должно быть `@app.shell_context_processor
                                              def make_shell_context():
                                                  return dict(db=db, Users=Users)`

Comment: Пока не получается (( Вот мой код на гите: https://github.com/DorimenUkraine/telegrambot_with_flask

Comment: Посмотрел код. Скрипт миграции создался у вас, в вашей базе еще должна появиться табличка alembic_version, там содежится номер последней ревизии скрипта миграции (на гитхабе это c9f9354a1d9d). Команда flask db init выполняется один раз, при создании базы. Повторно ее запускать не нужно. В процессе дальнейшей разработки, при внесении изменений в models.py вы выполняете только migrate/upgrade. Их повторное выполнение, если не менялся код, никаких изменений в существующую базу не должно вносить.

Comment: спасибо, что нашли время и посмотрели код. но дело в том, что если я ранее создал БД через db.create_all(), а потом допустим внес изменение в модели, то python app.py db migrate генерирует миграцию, в которой просто дропает все таблицы и все )

Comment: У вас  "неправильный" файл миграции. На апгрейд он удаляет таблицы, а на даунгрейд (когда возвращаемся к предыдущему состоянию) таблицы создаются. Попробуйте пересоздать все заново -- init/migrate/upgrade.